# How to run Neopixel without sudo permissions for use in an alexa app

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, led

I am creating an Alexa app that will allow the user to turn on a set of NeoPixels (WS2812) LEDs using a simple voice command. The app is hosted on a raspberry pi 4 and currently works for turning on GPIO pins. The issue I am having is that the code to turn on the NeoPixels needs sudo permissions, so when using the alexa app and it will simply error instead of turning on the lights.

due to the fact that sudo is needed the only way I have been able to run the script is to

```
sudo python3 LEDTest2.py
```

which works fine

here is the implementation for the alexa app turning on the GPIO pin and calling the python program

```
@ask.intent('GpioIntent', mapping = {'status':'status'})
def Gpio_Intent(status,room):
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)    
    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    if status in STATUSON:
        GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
        LEDTest2.func() ###Problem Point###
        return statement('turning {} lights'.format(status))
```

This works fine for turning on the GPIO pin

Here is the LEDTest2.func()

```
import board
import neopixel
import time
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18,60)

def func():
    print("func() in LEDtest2.py")
    pixels.fill((255, 197, 143))
    time.sleep(5)
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))

if __name__ == "__main__": #same as file one
    print("LEDtest2.py is being run directly")
    for x in range(2): 
        pixels.fill((0, 255, 0))
        time.sleep(.1)
        pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))
        time.sleep(.1)


else:
    print("LEDtest2.py is being imported into another module")
```

how can i run this code without needing sudo permissions? is there an alternative way to control WS2812 LEDs using python?

Edit: Just to clarify i am not having any problems with the GPIO pins it is the NeoPixel library that cannot be used without sudo permissions

Comment: Might be helpful https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root

Answer (score 1):

I was able to control it without sudo.
You should enable SPI interface from raspi-config.
Of course, first physically move LED connection to GPIO10 and change the pin in code.
I tried it and this works for me.